# pass variable from ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, post

i have 1 php file name index.php. in that file i want to pass one variable from ajax to php.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("mydiv").value;
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {   
        $.ajax(
        {   
            type:"POST",
            url: window.location.href,
            data: 'action='+elem,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cctv').hide();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#cctv').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#cctv').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("body");
        $container.load('findAllPath.php',{'function': 'findAllPath'});
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('findAllPath.php',{'function': 'findAllPath'});
        }, 10000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

and my php

```
if (isset ($_POST['action']))
{   
    echo $_POST['action'];
}
```

in firebug, i can see that ajax already post 'action=value' but in php, $_POST['action'] is empty.
anyone can help me, what's wrong with my code?
thank you

Comment: Does the isset test pass? Is it set but just to an empty string?

Comment: From where on the page is this javascript executed? For example, is it inside the `<head>` tag, or at the bottom, near `</body>`?

Comment: Try making `data` a hash rather than a query string.

Comment: @richard: isset test is not pass

Comment: @sverri: is in tag body

Comment: @all: thank you for your responds, finally i didn't use ajax, just js with setInterval only

Answer (score 4):

Try using data like this

```
data: {action: elem},
```

For Example

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: { name: "John", action: "save" }
   }).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

printr whole $_REQUEST and check if your are getting action

Answer (score 1):

set this as json object:

```
data: {action: elem}
```

and don't mix jquery with pure js.

```
var elem = $('#myDiv').val();
```

and as friend above say. There can be situation where js is trying to get value property before whole page is loaded. You should do everything in document ready block.

You can also do:

```
data: {
action: $('#myDiv').val()
}
```

You will be sure then that you have the newest data on the form!

Answer (score 1):

Look in to this and find what you have missed

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: { action: elem}
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#cctv').hide();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#cctv').show();
        },
        success: function() {
            $('#cctv').show();
        }
    });
    var $container = $("body");
    $container.load('findAllPath.php',{'function': 'findAllPath'});
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $container.load('findAllPath.php',{'function': 'findAllPath'});
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: hmm?i don't get it,, if you mean url: "some.php" and not window.location.href, is not make any different

Comment: data: 'action='+elem, this is the wrong one, are you not getting answer or unable to understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_POST['action']))
{   
echo $_POST['action'];
}
```

Try this code...

Comment: but $_POST['action'] is undefined, so empty test will not pass